# How to find golden mean position for window or html document?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing an custom alert dialog component in javascript ( using jquery ). I need to show the alert dialog in the golden mean position of the window or document similar to our javascript alert. I have tried one calculation. But this is not compatible with javascript alert. I want to calculate top and left position in js and not in css.

My calculation is as follows

```
Var windowHeight = $(window).height(),
      windowWidth = $(window).width(),
      smallerPortion = windowHeight - ( windowHeight / 1.618 ),
      dialogTop = smallerPortion - ( $(dialogElement).height( ) / 2 ),
      dialogLeft = windowWidth - ( $(dialogElement).width( ) / 2 );
```

"dialogTop" and "dialogLeft" are the calculated values.

P.S: dialogElement is my div element holding the custom alert dialog contents.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript alerts cannot be positioned.

You'll have to write your own HTML/CSS to display a message. You might consider starting with something like Bootstrap's Modals.

Comment: Yes i don't want to position javascript alert. I want to position my custom alert dialog.

Comment: @KuKa OK, so use CSS positioning to do so. You've provided no code for us to look at.

Comment: I have added my code sample @ceejayoz. I want to find position in js and not in css.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the in-built alert method

```js
var alert = function(data){

  var template = "<div>"+data+"</div>";
  
 //use your logic here and apply CSS as you want and inject the template in 'body' or any 'div'
  

}
```

Comment: This won't work if the invoking code assumes that the `alert` function will block until the user closed the dialog. You cannot block the main thread with a custom dialog.